# Firebase RTDB offline mode: Read from cache first

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use offline mode with the setting `keepSynced(true)` for some RTDB nodes. It works as expected, but it would be better for me to read data from the local cache first. Currently, when read some it takes a delay of about 5-7 seconds before I get data when offline. My guess is this delay comes when Firebase SDK tries to get data from the cloud first. So can I change the default read strategy? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're [using `get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_get) to read the data, which is defined as ensuring you get the value from the server and so may take some time.

If you want to get the value from the cache immediately, either [use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_a_listener) or (preferably) [use `addValueEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_with_persistent_listeners).

Comment: The only issue with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is that it doesn't fire any callback when local cache has not contain requested data (when offline)

Comment: Correct, that's why you should use `get` or (preferable) `addValueEventListener`. Really: that's the only way to get both a fast response when the data is cached and a response when its not cached yet.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be better for me to read data from the local cache first.

That only happens when you're offline. While online, there is no way you can read the data from the cache. The Firebase Realtime Database SDK always tries to get data from the server. That's a behavior specific to the Realtime Database, however, if you plan to use Firestore, then what you're looking for is possible. You can call [Query#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) and specify the source. So in your case, it should be [Source#CACHE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Source#CACHE).